# Creating a function which reverses iterator

Tags: python, object, iterator, iteration

I'm doing this in attempt to better understand the `iter()` and `next()` methods better.

So I understand this can easily be done like this using some built-ins:

```
>>>animal = 'cat'
>>>print(list(reversed(animal)))
['t','a','c']
```

But this can also be done creating a class iterable:

```
class Reverselist():
    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data
        self.index = len(data)

    def __iter__(self):
        return self

    def __next__(self):
        if self.index == 0:
            raise StopIteration
        self.index =self.index -1
        return self.data[self.index]

    def intolist(self):
        self.test = [i for i in self]
        return self.test

rev = Reverselist('cat')
print(rev.intolist())

['t','a','c']
```

However, I'm having some trouble doing the same thing but using functions instead of going the OOO route.

Is there a way to do this with functions using `iter()` and `next()` methods without having to resort to comprehensions and loops?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "using functions"? It should be easy your own reverse list iterator as a generator function, but you'll need at least one loop of some kind (either `while index > 0` or a `for index in range(len(lst)-1,-1,-1)`).

Comment: Don't confuse iterators and iterables. An iterator doesn't necessarily have to generate a finite sequence, and so doesn't have a last element to start with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a [generator function](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/):

```
def reverse_list(seq):
    for index in range(len(seq)-1, -1, -1):
        yield seq[index]
```

Calling this function will produce a "generator object" that supports `iter()` and `next()`.

```
>>> rev = reverse_list('cat')
>>> rev
<generator object reverse_list at 0x10a93ebe0>
>>> next(rev)
't'
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I was more looking for a way to do this using `iter()`and `next()` explicitly? I understand that makes it more difficult than it should be.

Comment: @bLunt If you want to specify the behavior of `iter()` and `next()` explicitly, then use your original approach of defining an object with `__iter__` and `__next__` methods.